# batch file to rename files also tries to rename directories

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

The following batch file works to take directory and file names from a txt file and rename the files in the directory according to the names given.

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

(for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=;" %%A in ('"TYPE C:\RENAME-ALL.txt"') do (
echo %%A | find /i "\" 
 if !errorlevel! equ 1 (
RENAME "D:\!mypath!%%A" "%%B" 
 ) ELSE (
echo "found pattern"
echo %%A
set  mypath=%%A
  echo mypath is !mypath!
 )
)
) >> C:\RENAME-ALL-4.txt 2>&1
endlocal
```

```
========== RENAME-ALL.TXT ================

mydirectory\photos\2019\  <= this is the directory
IMG_20190729_064619.jpg;IMG_20190825_064619.jpg   <=former name is replaced by the latter name
```

In this case, the batch file renames the file IMG_20190729_064619.jpg in the mydirectory\photos\2019 to IMG_20190825_064619.jpg.

However, the batch file also tries to rename mydirectory\photos\2019 to "" (This should not happen.) Can this be suppressed? How?

Comment: Another option is to test if `%%A` is a directory.  There are several ways to do that.   Lots of questions that have been answered about that on StackOverFlow.  So search away.

Comment: @Squashman I believe `echo %%A | find /i "\"` is testing for directory. If "\" is not found, then, that line isn't a directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

(for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=;" %%A in ('"TYPE C:\RENAME-ALL.txt"') do if "%%B"=="" (
  echo "found pattern"
  echo %%A
  set  "mypath=%%A"
  echo mypath is !mypath!
 ) ELSE (
  RENAME "D:\!mypath!%%A" "%%B" 
 )
) >> C:\RENAME-ALL-4.txt 2>&1
endlocal
```